# Trigger intent when document data changed in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

Let's say i have opted user for the push notifications and user granted permission to receive the notifications. The user  information are stored in the firestore database and user has monthly invoices in another third party system and that system will update the invoices to firestore whenever an invoice is billed.Now whenever the invoices are updated(inserted) into firestore i want to trigger an dialogflow intent which will send the push notification to the user and when the user tabs the push notification the latest invoice details should be displayed.

I have gone through the knowledge docs but i don't see any proper sample to achieve the above use case. Could you please help to achieve the same.

Comment: You can use [Cloud Functions For Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).

Comment: @Alex Mamo Could you please share samples if you have anything.I don't see anything on the internet.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "i have opted user for the push notifications and user granted permission to receive the notifications"?

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow work on a conversational model, so does not currently allow for triggering an Intent out of band but sending something to the user.

There are exceptions. For example, notifications using Actions on Google does allow this to some extent. But this does not directly involve Dialogflow to send the notification itself.